# HTML audio stops playing after few minutes

Tags: java, html, audio

I am playing an audio on a .jsp file. but it stops after 4-5 minutes playing. How can I slove this. whole audio is 30minutes long. The audio play code is as follows.

```
        <audio hidden="true" controls autoplay>
            <source src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ImageServlet/<%=qp.getAudio().getPath()%>" type="audio/mp3">
        </audio>
```

Comment: Did you try to play the audio file before to make sure the file itself is not broken? Do you get any errors/warnings?

Comment: i got this error in the console of chrome browser

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH